# Trigger Collider Flickering

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to unity and I'm making a simple tag game with car like players. However, I'm having problems with my trigger collider. When I tag the other car it kind of flickers the is tagged true/false. Here is my code.

```
public Color TaggedColor;
public Color NoTaggedColor;
public bool Tagged;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Tagged = true;
    GetComponent<Image>().color = TaggedColor;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{

    if (other.tag == "P2")
    {
        if (Tagged == false)
        {
            Tagged = true;
            GetComponent<Image>().color = TaggedColor;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Tagged == true)
            {
                Tagged = false;
                GetComponent<Image>().color = NoTaggedColor;
            }
        }

        Debug.Log("TAG!");
    }


}

void GotTagged()
{
    if (Tagged == false)
    {
        Tagged = true;
        //GetComponent<Image>().color = TaggedColor;
    }

}

void TaggedOtherPlayer()
{
    if (Tagged == true)
    {
        Tagged = false;
        GetComponent<Image>().color = NoTaggedColor;
    }

}
```

I have a Second code for P2 that the only change is the start and the tag is P1. I'm not sure if this problem is something in my code or if it's the collider it's self. If anyone has any idea why this is happening I would love to hear it!

Update: I bevile the issue is coming from the Colliders because I have an empty as a child of both players that is the trigger collider. However when I tag one the other trigger goes off as well. Should I have only one trigger? And if so how would I go about doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you tag a player SetActive(false) the empty triggers for about 1 second or so. If you had a button that whenever its pressed it changes s value from true to false the false to true if you press and hold that button it will "flicker" back and forth between true and false. Thats what's happening with your players the trigger is constantly being pulled while you're touching so make it inactive for long enough for you to not be touching anymore. I hope that makes sense.